# Windows named pipes in practice

Tags: python, windows, winapi, named-pipes

With Windows named pipes, what is the proper way to use the `CreateNamedPipe`, `ConnectNamedPipe`, `DisconnectNamedPipe`, and `CloseHandle` calls?

I am making a server app which is connecting to a client app which connects and disconnects to the pipe multiple times across a session.

When my writes fail because the client disconnected, should I call `DisconnectNamedPipe`, `CloseHandle`, or nothing on my handle.

Then, to accept a new connection, should I call `CreateNamedPipe` and then `ConnectNamedPipe`, or just `ConnectNamedPipe`?

I would very much like an explanation of the different states my pipe can be in as a result of these calls, because I have not found this elsewhere.

Additional info:

Language: Python using the `win32pipe`,`win32file` and `win32api` libraries.

Pipe settings: WAIT, no overlap, bytestream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to achieve what I wanted. I call `CreateNamedPipe` and `CloseHandle` exactly once per session, and I call `DisconnectNamedPipe` when my write fails, followed by another `ConnectNamedPipe`.

The trick is to only call `DisconnectNamedPipe` when the pipe was actually connected. I called it every time I tried to connect "just to be sure" and it gave me strange errors.

See also djgandy's answer for more information about pipes.

Answer (score 5):

It is good practice to call `DisconnectNamedPipe` then `CloseHandle`, although `CloseHandle` should clean everything up.

The MSDN documentation is a little vague and their [server example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is pretty basic. As to whether you reuse pipe handles, it seems that it is your own choice. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `DisconnectNamedPipe` seems to indicate that you can re-use a pipe handle for a new client by calling `ConnectNamedPipe` again on that handle after disconnecting. The role of `ConnectNamedPipe` seems to be to assign a connecting client to a handle.

Make sure you are cleaning up pipes though as MSDN states [the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Every time a named pipe is created, the system creates the inbound and/or outbound buffers using nonpaged pool, which is the physical memory used by the kernel. The number of pipe instances (as well as objects such as threads and processes) that you can create is limited by the available nonpaged pool. Each read or write request requires space in the buffer for the read or write data, plus additional space for the internal data structures.

I'd also bare the above in mind if you are creating/destroying a lot of pipes. My guess that it would be better to operate a pool of pipe handles if there are many clients and have some grow/shrink mechanism to the pool.